# Logic error when using Newton-Raphson method in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the approximated square root of a number in python using the Newton-Raphson method(The formula)

[image]

However the code does not work as it is stuck in the while loop(at least I think so). My plan is to calculate approximations until approximations differ by 1e–10.
This is the code I have right now:

```
k = input("Enter a number")
try:
    k = int(k)
    xi = 1
    xi2 = xi - (xi**2 - k)/(xi*2)
    diff = xi2 - xi
    while (diff > 0.0000000001):
        xi = xi2
        xi2 = xi - (xi**2 - k)/(xi*2)
        print(xi2)
    print(xi2)
except:
    print("bye")
```

I'm new to python so any help will be much appreciated! thanks a lot! :)

Update:
I tried using the code below as some answer suggested, however when giving the input 2 it only gives me one loop before giving the answer(1.4166666666666667). The correct answer should be (1.4142135623730951).

```
while (diff > 0.0000000001):
    xi = xi2
    xi2 = xi - (xi**2 - k)/(xi*2)
    diff = xi2 - xi
```

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: Your never changing `diff` in your while loop, so won't `diff > 0.0000000001` always be `True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not changing the `diff` within the loop. The diff is always the initial value you assigned, so it never becomes less than 1e-10

```
while (diff > 0.0000000001):
        xi = xi2
        xi2 = xi - (xi**2 - k)/(xi*2)
        diff=xi2-xi
```

**EDIT:**

Your problem is not a programming one. 
After running some iterations with a `print(diff)` added to the `while` block I noticed there were negative values involved.

Consider a value of `- 1e-2`. It does satisfy the loop break condition because it's less than `1e-10`, but it's actually a big distance away from desired result.

If you are dealing with differences, use absolutes:

```
k = input("Enter a number ")
k = int(k)
xi = 1
xi2 = xi - (xi**2 - k)/(xi*2)
diff = abs(xi2 - xi)
#0.0000000001
while (diff > 0.0000000001):
    xi = xi2
    xi2 = xi - (xi**2 - k)/(xi*2)
    diff = abs(xi2 - xi)
    print(diff)
print(xi2)
```

Output:

```
$ python newton-raphson.py
Enter a number 2
0.08333333333333326
0.002450980392156854
2.123899820016817e-06
1.5947243525715749e-12
1.4142135623730951
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I've tried to do that before however it only loops once before giving the answer(1.4166666666666667). The correct answer should be (1.4142135623730951)

Comment: @pooroll I adjusted the answer